# How many sump pits should I have?

Tags: basement, foundation, waterproofing, sump-pump

I have an older french drain system and after experiencing some foundation problems (horizontal crack), I've been told that my system should be updated to a more modern one which has weeping holes in the blocks so that water trapped behind them can get out.

The existing system has 2 sump pits, one in each corner on the rear wall. One contractor claims I need to add a 3rd pit to another wall while the other says I can keep the two pits on the rear wall. My existing system has never let water into the basement, it was just suggested I add weeping hole to it but it seems that can't be done without ripping up the old system.

Who is giving the better advice here? The one who want's to add the 3rd pit says the distance is too far for the drains to get to, while the other says it's fine.

My basement is laid out like: (Where the # is a sump pit)

30ft
|-----------------|
|....................|
|....................|
|....................| 25ft
|.#..............#.|
|-----------------|

Comment: How often do your sump pumps run?

Comment: They only run when it rains. The pits do have standing water in them at any given time (bout half full id say). When it rains, they'll cycle every minute or so.